# How to create a custom metabox like the wordpress provided tag metabox?

Tags: metabox

I want to create a custom meta box like this: 
[image]

What's the code I should add and where file should i add it in? I'm using wordpress' 2017 theme

Comment: Do you only want the meta box? Or do you want the rest of the behaviour of tags too? It sounds like you want a custom [taxonomy](https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/): https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/

Comment: Also, have a look at https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator-v2-beta/ Creating meta boxes from scratch can be tedious.